# How do I add a decision branch label in Enterprise Architect 9.3?

Tags: uml

How do I add a Decision branch label in Enterprise Architect 9.3?

It is a very basic thing I guess. But [this help page](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_languages/decision.html%20Decision%20Element) explains everything except what you expect from a help page, i.e. describing how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple, but the terminology is not obvious unless you are confident in using Enterprise Architect.

Double click the connector, select the 'Constraints' tab and the put your label text in the 'Guard' field.